# php - Make links clickable with http check

Tags: php

My function works without any problem with ftp, http and https

```
function makeClickableLinks($s) {
    return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', 
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $s);
}
```

However, it doesnt make clickable if url is www.example.org (if there is no http)

If I replace the `((f|ht)tp(s)?://)` to www , it works, however, if url has http, it makes clickable only after http part.

How can I make it work correctly both with http and without http ?

Comment: Can you make a https://regex101.com/

Comment: If the URL is just `www.example.org`, you'll have to fix it up into `http://www.example.org` to begin with; just `href="www.example.org"` either won't work as you expect or is invalid, depending on your definition. So, you'll need to produce a separate regex and replace for that, you cannot cram it into this regex.

Comment: This seems to work: https://regex101.com/r/s49eS9/1 - But just like @deceze says, this will produce an invalid link for all www links (that's missing http(s)). You can solve this by simply run `str_replace('a href="www.', 'a href="http://www.', $string);` after your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seem to cut it. It checks if any string starts with http, https, ftp or www.

It also fixes all invalid links (that starts with just www).

Here you can test just the regex: https://regex101.com/r/s49eS9/2

```
function makeClickableLinks($s)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/((((f|ht)tp(s)?:\/\/)|www)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;\/\/=]+)/i', function($matches) {
        if (substr($matches[0], 0 , 4) == 'www.') {
            // The match starts with www., add a protocol (http:// being the most common).
            $matches[0] = 'http://' . $matches[0];
        }

        return '<a href="' . $matches[0] . '">' . $matches[0] . '</a>';
    }, $s);
}
```

**Note:** Just like @deceze points out in his comment, this will not work for ALL url's, like `example.com`. Making a regex that converts all versions of all valid URL's would be a much bigger task and you would probably need to list all valid TLD's.

**Edit:** Change from `str_replace()` to use `preg_replace_callback()` to sort out the invalid www-link-situation, as suggested by @deceze

Comment: This of course doesn't work for just `example.com`, or `www2.example.com`, or any other domain not starting with `www.` (which become increasingly less common I'd say). It also feels pretty icky to me to do a `str_replace` on the replaced HTML…

Comment: @deceze - I know that this won't work for a bunch of different URL's. Today, it's almost impossible to make this work 100% since there are so many new TLD's (and more keeps getting added). But this does answer the OP's question. I don't agree with the icky part, though. It's not worse than running multiple regex's, for example.

Comment: I'd use a `preg_replace_callback` and fix up the link in there before putting it into HTML… Again, it just feels icky to me… Just my .02€.

Comment: @deceze - That was actually a valid and good .02€ that I didn't think of!

Comment: Really, in practice, I'd use a dedicated library for this task. As you say, this can get really complex really quickly and is really not a wheel that needs reinventing…

Comment: @deceze - Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Sorry the corruption was from the htmlentites() tag which should be used before using your function, I removed my comments, your function works perfectly, thanks Magnus ;)